# How to grep a string from a file starting from a pattern and ending from a pattern

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
user=datab-admin-role
allusers="datab-admin-111role datab-admin-112role datab-admin-113role "
if(...)
then..
...
```

I want to grep only the first occurrence of a string starting with   `datab` and ending with `role` in a variable.

What I am trying is:

```
 sed -n '/datab/,/role/p' filename
```

But it returns all the strings with datab and also it returns it as:

```
user=datab-admin-role
```

I want it to only return `datab-admin-role` and assign it to a variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use grep for this:

```
grep -o -m 1 'datab[A-Za-z0-9-]*role' filename
```

The `-o` flag means only returned the part of the line that matches the pattern, not the whole line.

The `-m 1` flag means return the first occurrence only.

The pattern is anything starting with `datab` followed by only letters, digits and hyphens,, then `role`, which is what I assume you want, since you don't just want a longer string with space or punctuation or something else inside.

To assign to a variable:

```
myvar="$(grep -o -m 1 'datab[A-Za-z0-9-]*role' filename )"
```

But I'm sure there's a way to do it with `sed` as well.

Answer (score 2):

I'd likely use [the posted grep solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1397253/178692) however you can do it in sed using a *capture group*.

In sed, `/pattern1/,/pattern2/` addresses a *range of lines* between matching patterns - if you want to match between patterns on a single line you need something like

```
sed -n '/.*\(datab.*role\).*/{s//\1/p;q;}' filename
```

where the `\(` and `\)` define a capture group, and `\1` back-references it, omitting any leading `.*` and trailing `.*` characters to simulate grep's `-o` or `--only-matching` flag (and we `q`uit after the first match to simulate grep's `-m1`).

Or using GNU sed

```
sed -En 's/.*(datab.*role).*/\1/p;T;q' filename
```

(here the `T` branches past the `q` until the `s` succeeds).

You can change `(datab.*role)` to `(datab[A-Za-z0-9-]*role)` for a more restrictive match if necessary.

Comment: What does `s//\1/p;` do? It seems to be replacing nothing with `\1` and printing. Is `s//` shorthand for `s/.*/`?

Answer (score 1):

A perl approach:

```
$ perl -lne 'if(/datab.+?role/){print $&; exit}' file
datab-admin-role
```

The `-l` adds a newline to every `print` call and strips trailing newlines from each input line. The `-n` means "read the input file line by line and apply the script given by `-e` to each line".

The script itself tries to match `datab` then the shortest possible string (`.+?`) until the first `role`. If this is found, we print what was matched (the special variable `$&`) and exit.

To store in a variable, just do:

```
var=$(perl -lne 'if(/datab.+?role/){print $&; exit}' file)
```

Comment: thanks a lot. it worked!!!!